# Python opencv aeroplane condensation trail detection

Tags: python, opencv, scale, contour

My task is to detect aeroplane condensation trails on the blue sky and deleting everything else from the picture, but I have to leave a 10-pixel wide area around the trails.

I have managed to draw the contours of the condensation trails based on colour using a mask and cv2.drawContours but I'm stuck with creating that 10-pixel sky blue area around it-basically I have to scale up the contour line.

Is it possible to scale up contours drawn by the cv2.drawContours command?

Comment: you can increase the thickness while drawing contours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a list of points on the contour, you can easily draw a 10-pixel thick line on it by using the [`line`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) function between consecutive points (look at the thickness parameter). To fill the rest of the area inside the contour, look at the [`fillPoly`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly) function.